# Turn off auto redirect in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, cookies, windows-phone-8.1

I have a POST request, that return code 302.

```
string FormParams = "Some_string";
byte[] SomeBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FormParams);

HttpWebRequest AuthPost = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://example.com/");
AuthPost.Method = "POST";
AuthPost.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

AuthPost.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
AuthPost.Headers["Referer"] = "https://example.com/";
AuthPost.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; ASU2JS; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
AuthPost.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
AuthPost.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
AuthPost.Headers["DNT"] = "1";
AuthPost.Headers["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive";
AuthPost.Headers["Cookie"] = savedcookie;
AuthPost.Headers["Content-Length"] = SomeBytes.Length.ToString();
AuthPost.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
Stream postStream = await AuthPost.GetRequestStreamAsync();
postStream.Write(SomeBytes, 0, SomeBytes.Length);
postStream.Flush();

HttpWebResponse AuthPostResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await AuthPost.GetResponseAsync();
```

So I need manage returned cookie before redirecting.
How can I turn off auto redirect or manage cookies?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage cookies"? Generally, I would say `AllowAutoRedirect` should do the job of preventing the auto redirect, I don't quite understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: AllowAutoRedirect is not available in Windows Phone 8.1 That's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CookieContainer Property/Class. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

You can reuse the container in other requests.